# Laravel Query - Only the top amount for each day of the week

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a function which shows me the best day, for each of the days of the week.

So say we had:

```php
Order::join('order_items', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_items.order_id')
    ->where('orders.paid', 1)
    ->groupBy('orders.paid_at')
    ->select(DB::raw(
        'orders.paid_at,
        DATE_FORMAT(orders.paid_at, \'%W\') AS week_day,
        SUM(order_items.amount) AS amount'
    ))->orderBy('amount', 'DESC');
```

So it would eventually output

```
2019-04-29, Monday, £500
2019-01-01, Tuesday, £700
2019-02-06, Wednesday, £400
2019-01-03, Thursday, £600
2019-02-15, Friday, £200
2019-04-20, Saturday, £100
2019-03-17, Sunday, £600
```

My current query selects every single Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday and gives the amount for each occurrence.

I would like to only show the best performing date, for each of the days of the week (giving us 7 rows).

Is there a way to wrap a query around this query to achieve that or another way?

Comment: Your query seems fine to me. I've tested it myself and it gives back just 7 results one for each day. Make sure that your `$this->from` or `$this->to` variables are not just empty string but they represent a date, for example '2019-05-04' or whatever format you store it in the DB.

Comment: The problem is that it returns every single Monday for example, I only want 1 of each day of the week, but the one with the highest amount

Comment: As I said if your whereBetween uses for example the current week: 
`['2019-04-29', '2019-05-05']` that week contains only one Monday, so there is no way it will give you two days Monday. And also, you are making a SUM of the amounts for each day, so if you want just the most paid on Monday, then you should remove the SUM and just get the amount.

Comment: Ah sorry for not being clear. It must include multiple Monday's, as the purpose is to show the most revenue generated on a Monday during that period.

Comment: Okay, can you please edit your question with a simple input meaning dates, and what is expected output? Because from what is given it is still not clear at least to me.

Comment: @nakov I have updated the question, removed the from/to which was confusing things and given the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to produce the expected results, I added one extra column to the select in order to be able to sort the days as expected at the end. The solution is not completely mysql one, but using the collection methods it is done easily I believe. So please try this and let me know.

```
Order::join('order_items', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_items.order_id')
    ->where('orders.paid', 1)
    ->groupBy('orders.paid_at')
    ->select(DB::raw(
        'orders.paid_at,
        DAYNAME(orders.paid_at) AS week_day, // this function gives the same as formatting
        WEEKDAY(orders.paid_at) as day,
        SUM(order_items.amount) AS amount'
    ))->orderBy('amount', 'DESC')
      ->get()
      ->unique('week_day')->sortBy('day'); // this two will give the expected result
```

Comment: it reduces it down to the 7 days of the week, but the order by amount desc doesn't seem to be respected with the unique function, it seems to not start from the top

Comment: I have got it working, the group by paid_at needed date applying to it, so that it wasn't grouping by the hour, minute and seconds of the order

Comment: Okay, I wasn't aware of the paid_at field, I thought it was just a date, not a datetime. 
Happy if it helped somehow. Please consider accepting the answer if this was good.

Comment: Accepted! I think longer term without using a collection would be good, but it solves the problem for now. There's 100's of thousands of rows int he database, so I think completely mysql might be more efficient.