# Get day name from DB::raw date format in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here is my code

```
Attendance::select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(date, "%D, %d %M %y") as date'))
    ->where('id', $objAttendance->id)
    ->first();
```

But it returns :

```
"date" => "19th, 19 March 22"
```

i need date like "Monday, 19 March 2022"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By keep searching, I get it by adding `%W` :

```
Attendance::select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(date, "%W, %d %M %y") as date'))
    ->where('id', $objAttendance->id)
    ->first();
```

Here is the link of answer :
[Laravel Query - Only the top amount for each day of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55981682/laravel-query-only-the-top-amount-for-each-day-of-the-week)